# How to make contents of a table editable on clicking Edit button

Tags: angular6

In one of my `Angular` components, I show some values in form of a table. There is an `edit` button. I want that when the `edit` button is clicked, I can edit the values of the table. Eg, on clicking edit, the row with angular reference variable `#titleColumn` becomes editable by removing `readonly` property from the `textarea`.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="question-details-table">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><strong>Title</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="data-row">
      <td #titleColumn colspan="2"><textarea name="question-title" rows="1" readonly>{{practiceQuestion.title}}</textarea></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I suppose I can use either `Renderer2` or `ElementRef` directly in my `Component` or I can use a `Directive` and add the `Directive` to `td` elements. But I don't know how either of these could be done

- `ElementRef`, what would be the type of `nativeElement` for `TextArea`? Can I set and remove attribute `readonly` using it?
- How can I access the `td` elements using `Renderer2`?
- If I create a `Directive` like follows (picked from https://alligator.io/angular/using-renderer2/), how can i dynamically add/remove it? (sorry, I am  not able to sort out the formatting)

```
    import { Directive, Renderer2, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Directive({
      selector: '[appGoWild]'
    })
    export class GoWildDirective implements OnInit {

      constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) {}


      ngOnInit() {

        this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'wild');

      }

    }

    <h1 appGoWild>

      Hello World!

    </h1>

    <!-- <h1 class="wild">Hello World!</h1> -->
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use angular mat table inline edit...
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-inline-editing